# Format pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a table that looks like this:

[image: Table 1]

But I want it to look like this:

[image: Table2]

When there is only one league I can get it to look like it but when there are multiple leagues I don't know how to. If it can't be done then I'll manually format it but it would be nice to do it automatically before saving it to a file.

```
df.drop(df.columns[2], axis=1, inplace=True) # get rid of All column
df.drop(df.columns[3], axis=1, inplace=True) # get rid of KO column
df.drop(df.columns[4], axis=1, inplace=True) # get rid of All.1 column
df.columns = ['League', 'Home', 'Home Team', 'Away Team', 'Away'] # rename columns
df = df.replace(to_replace=np.nan, value='0%') # replace NaN values with 0%
for x in range(len(df.index)):
    df.loc[x,'League'] = df.loc[0,'League'] # get league name and copy it to every row in column 0
df = df.drop(df.index[0]) # get rid of top row
```

That's my current code to remove the columns I don't want and copy league names but it only works when there is one league and not multiple ones.

Any solutions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and have a look on [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df1 = df.ffill()
df1 = df1[~df1.eq(df1['Unnamed: 0'], axis='index').all(1)]
```

---

**df1:**

```
    Unnamed: 0  Home    All Home Team   KO      Away Team   All.1   Away
1   League 1    100%    50% Team 1      23:00   Team 2      0%      0%
2   League 1    100%    50% Team 3      23:00   Team 4      53%     53%
4   League 2    75%     75% Team 5      20:00   Team 6      29%     29%
6   League 3    50%     75% Team 7      14:00   Team 8      50%     67%
7   League 3    0%      17% Team 9      14:00   Team 10     50%     50%
```

Comment: Now you can filter out by passing the columns name :)